# win7: setting user group to have elevated privileges to access files fails to allow application to access

Tags: windows-7, privileges

I'm a programmer not an admin.  I significantly modified an old program written in 1997 to run under Windows XP ~7 years ago.  At that time, I rewrote in VC++ 2005.  The local production network has been updated to Win7.  Program updated to VC++ 2010.

Problem: Program runs in new environment but only if user has admin privileges.  Without, needed files cannot be accessed.  Attempted Fix has been to give user group access to the needed files.  Users can access the files "by hand" but program still fails.

Is there a way to give the application admin privileges so that it can access the files?

Not acceptable is allowing users to run as admin.  We have to operate under DoD constraints.  Is there something I as the guy working on the application can do?  If not, what is the solution?

Comment: No, you can't (safely) give an application admin privilege, you need to identify and fix the underlying problem.  There are a number of ways you can try to identify the problem.  Process Monitor can be useful.  There's also the [SUA tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744768(v=vs.85).aspx) which I've never used but is highly relevant.  Also, try logging in as a new user and double-check that it still doesn't work; the existing users might have left-over virtualized files or registry settings.

Comment: Note that if all of your API calls have correct error handling, it should be easy to find the failing call(s) and examine exactly what is happening in the debugger.

Comment: I know precisely where the error is occurring.  Attempting to open a text file with rw access throws the error.  There is insufficient privilege to access the file.  This is the problem we're trying to solve.

Comment: Addendum: Attempting to open a text file with rw access throws the error.  There is insufficient privilege to access the file.  This is the problem we're trying to solve.  NOTE: the program cannot be run in debug mode because the network is classified and MS VC++ is not permitted to be installed.  Application is compiled on another machine and then installed.

Comment: If you know which line of code is failing, please post it, along with enough of the preceding code to show us what is happening.  Also post the information Process Monitor shows for the failed operation.  As for debugging, surely you have or can create a test machine with the same configuration as the production machine?  One thought in the meantime: probably the *most* common cause for the symptom you describe (taken by itself) is that the file is already open, and unfortunately this produces the same error code you would get if the user didn't have permission.

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem.  I'll make some code changes and test next week when the Admin is here.  This old program edits a scratch/temporary file that is on the user's C: directory.  Mucking around with the C: directory is verboten.  Simplest is just change the code to put the file on a directory to which the user has access.  I'm 99% confident that this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Recap: problem was a large number of scratch files which, in the original application, were being written to the C:\ root directory.  The solution was to use "getenv_s" to obtain the user's directory via an environment variable.  The pathname was modified such that the string returned from "getenv_s" was concatenated with the scratch file name.  Laborious but problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The huge difference between XP and Windows 7 is the access system (user access control entered with Vista and was further refined in 7).  In theory you could run the application as an admin user, or provide a service that would access the necessary system components and files as an admin user.  But there isn't a way of giving an application itself extra permissions.

Your other option is to find out what specifically is causing the problem and correct that in your application.  Chances are this is a system file or the like.